# Handle UWP AutoSuggestionBox events the MVVM way

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, .net-core

I am trying to create an `AutoSuggestBox` that allows the user to search for a specific weather station.

To handle the `TextChanged` event I added a binding to the respective ViewModel property in the markup:

```
    <AutoSuggestBox Grid.Row="1" 
                    PlaceholderText="Station" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    QueryIcon="Forward"
                    Width="300"
                    Height="50"
                    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                    TextMemberPath="Name"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Stations}">

        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="TextChanged">
                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TextChanged}"></core:InvokeCommandAction>
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

    </AutoSuggestBox>
```

My ViewModel looks as follows:

```
public class StationCollectionVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private IStationManager stationManager;
    private ICommand textChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<StationVM> Stations { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public StationCollectionVM(IStationManager stationManager)
    {
        this.stationManager = stationManager;
        Stations = new ObservableCollection<StationVM>();
        LoadStations();
    }

    private async void LoadStations()
    {
        Stations.Clear();
        IEnumerable<Station> stations = await stationManager.GetAllStationsAsync();
        IEnumerator<Station> e = stations.GetEnumerator();
        while (await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => e.MoveNext()))
        {
            Stations.Add(new StationVM(stationManager, e.Current));
        }
    }

    public ICommand TextChanged
    {
        get
        {
            if (textChanged == null)
            {
                textChanged = new RelayCommand(args =>
                {
                    // ICommand.Execute(...) takes only 1 param.
                    // How do you get both the AutoSuggestBox and 
                    // AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs param
                    // sent from the AutoSuggestBox?

                    // Filter stations based on the user input here...
                });
            }
            return textChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that `RelayCommand` is just an implementation of `ICommand`:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    readonly Action<object> executeAction;
    readonly Predicate<object> canExecutePredicate;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
      : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        executeAction = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
        canExecutePredicate = canExecute;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        executeAction(parameter);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return canExecutePredicate == null ? true : canExecutePredicate(parameter);
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

How do I access both event parameters in  `StationCollectionVM`'s `TextChanged` property? Also, what is the preferred way to pass the filtered station list back to the AutoSuggestBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to filter data based on the input value of `AutoSuggestBox`, then only 1 argument is sufficient. You can pass `Text` property of `AutoSuggestBox` as a `CommandParamenter` like below:

```
<AutoSuggestBox x:Name="autoSuggestBox" 
                        Grid.Row="1" 
                        PlaceholderText="Station" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        QueryIcon="Forward"
                        Width="300"
                        Height="50"
                        DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                        TextMemberPath="Name"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ComboBoxList}">

                <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="TextChanged">
                        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TextChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=autoSuggestBox}"></core:InvokeCommandAction>
                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

</AutoSuggestBox>
```

Also, note that you need additional property to store your actual collection which you can retrieve in case of no filter value.

Your VM:

```
public class StationCollectionVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private IStationManager stationManager;
    private ICommand textChanged;
    private IEnumerable<StationVM> stationsVM { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<StationVM> Stations { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public StationCollectionVM(IStationManager stationManager)
    {
        this.stationManager = stationManager;
        Stations = new ObservableCollection<StationVM>();
        LoadStations();
    }

    private async void LoadStations()
    {
        Stations.Clear();
        IEnumerable<Station> stations = await stationManager.GetAllStationsAsync();
        IEnumerator<Station> e = stations.GetEnumerator();
        while (await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => e.MoveNext()))
        {
            stationsVM.Add(new StationVM(stationManager, e.Current));
        }
        Stations = ObservableCollection<StationVM>(stationsVM);
    }

    public ICommand TextChanged
    {
        get
        {
            if (textChanged == null)
            {
                textChanged = new RelayCommand(args =>
                {
                   if(!string.IsEmpty(args))
                   {
                     Stations = staionsVM.Where(x=>x.SomeTextProperty.StartsWith(args));
                   }
                   else
                   {
                     Stations = ObservableCollection<StationVM>(stationsVM);
                   }
                });
            }
            return textChanged;
        }
    }
}
```